# Strange SCons behavior - build vs clean dependencies

Tags: scons

I have a set of build scripts carefully connected in the main build file (each has 2 connection aliases, prior and final). One is used twice with different variant_dir and different env. They do copy final executable to the same place but that’s kept hidden from Scons (excerpts follow) and it doesn’t complain (and doesn’t remove them during –c, which is good).

**The puzzle**: while building Scons doesn’t even try to build build first ('ocaml-LKG'), only the last ('ocaml-output') but for –c it only cleans the first (which it hasn’t built :-) and not the last (which it has built).

To force it to build the first as well I add it’s final alias (top_LKG bellow) explicitly to the head of ‘all’ alias

```
all = env.Alias('all', [top]) ==> all = env.Alias('all', [top_LKG, top])
```

but then for cleanup it cleans only that and nothing else and I could’t find a way to force it to clean up everything.

Individual builds and cleanups run OK.

Any ideas, related experiences etc. ?

----- Excerpts -----
Make.scons (orchestration)

```
def Connect_Stages(prior):
    FStar_prior, top_FStar = SConscript('FStar.scons')
    if prior :  env.Depends(FStar_prior, prior)  
    env_OCaml  = env.Clone()
    Ocaml_prior, top_Ocaml = SConscript('ocaml-output.scons', exports={'My_env' : env_OCaml}, variant_dir='ocaml-output', duplicate=0)
    env.Depends(Ocaml_prior, top_FStar)
    return top_Ocaml

if 'vs-fstar' in COMMAND_LINE_TARGETS :
    top_NET = SConscript('FStar_NET.scons')
    vs_fstar = env.Alias('vs-fstar', top_NET)
elif 'boot-ocaml' in COMMAND_LINE_TARGETS :  # just LKG ocaml
    no_prior, top_LKG = SConscript('ocaml-output.scons', exports={'My_env' : env}, variant_dir='ocaml-LKG', duplicate=0)
    boot_ocaml = env.Alias('boot-ocaml', top_LKG)
elif 'extract' in COMMAND_LINE_TARGETS :
    top_FStar = SConscript('FStar.scons')
elif 'ocaml' in COMMAND_LINE_TARGETS :  # boot, extract, new ocaml
    top = Connect_Stages(None)
    env.Alias('ocaml', top)
    #env.Default(top)
elif 'all' in COMMAND_LINE_TARGETS :    # LKG ocaml, boot, extract, new ocaml
    env_LKG = env.Clone()
    no_prior, top_LKG = env_LKG.SConscript('ocaml-output.scons', exports={'My_env' : env_LKG}, variant_dir='ocaml-LKG', duplicate=0)
    top = Connect_Stages(top_LKG)
    all = env.Alias('all', [top])
```

ocaml-output.scons (final steps, hiding copies, final alias)

```
main_native = env.Command(ResPath + ResFile, '', 
                           ['$OCAMLBUILD $OCAMLBUILDARGS ' + ResFile
                            , Copy(File('../../bin/FStar.exe'), File(ResPath + ResFile))
                            , Copy(File('../../bin/FStar.ocaml'), File(ResPath + ResFile)) 
                           ])

final = env.Alias(this_dir +'-final', main_native)   # ocaml-output-final, ocaml-LKG-final
Return('prior', 'final')
```

Comment: can you paste example command lines? You say "when building", but don't specify if there were any command line arguments. This is important as you use COMMAND_LINE_TARGETS to enable/disable reading SConscripts

Comment: Command line uses each of them in turn to test hat they work. or not. For example: -f Make.scons -n --tree=prune,status all -c (and without -c of course, and the same for all "minor" stages. The full/all sequence would be ocaml-LKG,  FStar, ocaml-output. Principal logic is that ocaml-LKG builds compiler (FStar.exe) from last known good sources (from a repo), FStar.scons uses it to transform/extract new sources and then ocaml-output builds from these new sources using the exact same process. One could run separately with boot-ocaml, then with ocaml to achieve the same result.

Comment: And the puzzling thing is that with simple 'all' being set, SCons doesn't "recognize" LKG phase when building but does recognizes it when cleaning and in cleaning doesn't recognize ocaml-output phase, When I force LKG (with [top_LKG, top]) then cleanup cleans just LKG and nothing else.

Comment: Could you add your command lines and what you expect and what you get above in the full text? That way you can mark code blocks/etc. Much easier to read.

Comment: Also ideally paste the output of --tree=prune for each command line (in the full text with formatting..)

Comment: That's going to make for one long and ugly page. I'm going to try. Hope the site lets me delete all that latter

Comment: Maybe link to pastebin for --tree=prune output?